# asp.net mvc 5 how to render a ReactJS component using a javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, reactjs

I am using asp.net mvc 5 and have a view .cshtml file. On it I have a javascript function that I call when I click a button on the view. I am trying to load a react component in the javascript function into a div. Here is my function and syntax - can someone provide me the proper syntax to accomplish this task?

```
function loadCompanyComponent() {
        alert('hurray');
        React.render(<ManageBlockedManufacturersScreen />, document.getElementById('react'));
        }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @autodidit suggestion on using facebooks react compiler service I pasted in my react code which gave me the correct javascript code to put within my javascript function. It turned up to be:

```
function loadCompanyComponent() {
        alert('in');

        React.render(React.createElement(ManageBlockedManufacturersScreen, null), document.getElementById('react'));
    }
```

So again, my jsx files are bundled and included on the page. My view.cshtml file had a plain html button and a plain javascript function. This above syntax worked to get the react component out of the bundle and show it on my div.

Comment: btw the div on my page is named react so that is the second parameter to the React.Render code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the official way to accomplish this would be with one of the many Flux implementations such as Alt.js, but this also works:

```
var isActive = false;

function handleClick(){
    isActive = !isActive;
    React.render(<ShowHide component={ HelloWorld } active={ isActive } />, document.getElementById('container'));
}

var ShowHide = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        if (this.props.active) {
            return React.createElement(this.props.component);        
        }
        return false;
    }
});

var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        );
    }
});

document.getElementById("toggle-button").addEventListener("click", handleClick, false);
```

See it here: https://jsfiddle.net/j2o1hozo/1/

Comment: Thank you! There is one difference on my end though. My jsx files are all bundled and included on my page. So the plain html button and the javascript click handler  is not within the react component. Instead, it is on the view.cshtml file as normal javascript with a normal html button. So the jsx files are budndled and available to the page, but I cannot get the syntax down to render the react component from the bundled jsx files. Can you offer any suggestions on this task? Thank you! :)

Comment: Honestly, I'm still trying to determine good patterns myself. One thing I've tried is using Facebook's jsx compiler service (https://facebook.github.io/react/jsx-compiler.html) to transform just the initial React.render statement into plain JavaScript that I can include in a script tag on the page. For instance, the JSX line inside the handleClick function transforms to this:

React.render(React.createElement(ShowHide, {component:  HelloWorld, active:  isActive }), document.getElementById('container'));

But then you have to ensure that React is available to both the script and the component.